# Check Multiple and module of two BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1.95);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(0.65);

BigDecimal rem = x.remainder(y);
if (rem.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0.) {
    System.out.println("Not In mutilple of");
} else {
    System.out.println("In mutilple of");
}
System.out.println(rem);
```

> Not giving correct result for the above scenario.
>   given the input condition but giving incorrect result if it is in multiple of the second value

Comment: What is the correct result?

Comment: Correct Result should be In multiple of Because my aim is to check 1.95 is the multiple of 0.65

Answer (score 8):

### Explanation

Useing `new BigDecimal(double)` might lose precision, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-):

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

and:

```
BigDecimal x= new BigDecimal(1.95);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(0.65);

System.out.println(x); // 1.9499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
System.out.println(y); // 0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

---

### Solution

Use `BigDecimal(String val)`:

> The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>   writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly
>   equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally
>   recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this
>   one.

and

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1.95");
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("0.65");

System.out.println(x);  // 1.95
System.out.println(y);  // 0.65
System.out.println(x.remainder(y)); // 0.00
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the precision is lost at compile time ... when the literal is converted to an IEE floating point value.

Comment: Then it will give me incorrect result for the unscaled value which i am getting.

Comment: @TaherMahodia - What do you mean - please give a sample

Comment: @Scary Wombat It is giving incorrect result for unscaled value also    BigDecimal x= new BigDecimal(1.9499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875);
  BigDecimal y= new BigDecimal(0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625);

Comment: I want to check two bigdecimal number are multiple or not

Comment: so see my answer

Comment: BTW on @Sun machine/OS/Java Version `0.65` becomes `0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625` on my test bed it becomes `0.64999999999999995559107901499373838305473327636718750`

Answer (score 5):

Instantiate like

```
BigDecimal x= new BigDecimal("1.95");
BigDecimal y= new BigDecimal("0.65");
```

as not all float point number can be represented exactly as `double`s.

The output in your code shows
`0.65` ss `0.64999999999999995559107901499373838305473327636718750`

see https://study.com/academy/lesson/java-floating-point-numbers.html